# Spring Validation using Annotation @RegExp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Im using Spring form validation to validate the input fields entered by the user. I need help to include space in a particular field. Below is the validation annotation that Im using. But it does not seem to allow space.

```
@RegExp(value="([0-9|a-z|A-Z|_|$|.])*",message="value can contain only digits,alphabets or _ or . or $")
private String cName ;
```

I would like to know what value I need to include in the validation annotation to include space in the name

I tried to include '\s' in the exp value to include blank space. But it doesn't seem to work

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex String is not valid for your requirement.

Use the following regex instead:

```
 //([0-9|a-z|A-Z|\\_|\\$|\\.|\\s])+

@Test
public void testRegex() {
    String r = "([0-9|a-z|A-Z|\\_|\\$|\\.|\\s])+";
    assertTrue("Allows space", Pattern.matches(r, "test test"));
    assertTrue("Allows .", Pattern.matches(r, "12My.test"));
    assertTrue("Allows _", Pattern.matches(r, "My_123"));
    assertTrue("Allows $", Pattern.matches(r, "$ 1.0"));

}
```

Comment: Why the pipes `|` in the character class?